# How to rotate my camera orbit more smoothly with touch?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I rotate the camera orbit more smoothly instead of just rotation with touch? That is, if I touch off the screen after rotation, the camera still rotates smoothly for 2 seconds?

```
    public float _lerpRate = 0.64f;
    private float _xRotation;
    private float _yYRotation;


    private void Rotate(float xMovement, float yMovement)
    {
        _xRotation += xMovement;
        _yYRotation += yMovement;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //if(!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
        if(EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.touches[0].fingerId))
        {

        }
        else
        {           
        _xRotation = Mathf.Lerp(_xRotation, 0, _lerpRate);
        _yYRotation = Mathf.Lerp(_yYRotation, 0, _lerpRate);
        transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0, _xRotation, -_yYRotation);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Problem is that `Mathf.Lerp` **never** really reaches `0`. It only gets closer and closer. Could you explain execatly what the use case is and what you expect from the movement?

Comment: @derHugo I am rotating the camera around an object with touch. I want a smooth rotation as soon as I remove the finger off the screen after rotating the camera, so that the camera rotates smoothly over time like maybe for 2 seconds.